# Constant retry to publish queued checkpoints

Tags: stellar-core

my goal is to host a full archive node and I started a Stellar full sync process three days ago and it is still applying checkpoints. I am getting a command line output, that Stellar is constantly trying to retry publishing the checkpoints and I wonder if that is expected (applying checkpoints progress is 17% after three days!)

`Catching up: applying checkpoint 48468/276475 (17%)
Publishing 48467 queued checkpoints [63-3101887]: Retrying in 3141 sec: prepare-snapshot`

1. How are these two outputs connected?
2. Does the retry process indicate that something is wrong with my History Archive PUT settings or what does `publishing` mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug that was causing "publish" to happen even though the node was not in sync yet, it is fixed in 10.0.0 (next release).

See https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/issues/1268

It doesn't really hurt publish performance, it's just annoying as when your node will have finally replayed all of history, it will take an hour for it to publish to your archive.

17% seems pretty low after 3 days, I'd recommend reviewing iostat etc on your machine to ensure that you are not pegging the drive (assuming you're running on dedicated drives or using a database as a service offering such as Amazon RDS).

Comment: I set up a `HISTORY_PUT` command, but I frankly don't know if it would really work correctly. If the command would be corrupted, could this hurt  the performance?

Comment: I also checked `iostat` and the numbers seem fine. iowait is below 1%. and still `Catching up: applying checkpoint 74171/276475 (26%)`